# How to create list of Component for drag and drop CDK angular

Tags: angular, angulardraganddroplists

I trying to create drag and drop to list Components with drag and drop CDK of angular, like below, but the Components are not displayed properly.

App.component.ts

```js
import { RightSideCombinedComponent } from './right-side.component';
import { LeftSideComponent } from './left-side.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

innerComponenets: Array<any> = [
  RightSideCombinedComponent,
  LeftSideComponent,
  ];
constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  

  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    moveItemInArray(this.innerComponenets, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
  }
```

```html
<div cdkDropList cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal" class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
            <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of innerComponenets"  cdkDrag>
                {{item}}
                </div>
```

the screen displayed (The code of the components is displayed instead of the display of the components):
Before drag and drop:
[image]

Drag and drop:
[image]

After drag and drop:
[image]

Does anyone know how to do it right?

Comment: How are they not displayed properly? Please describe the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array=[0,1];

<div cdkDropList cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal" class="example-list"
      (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
  <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of array" cdkDrag>
      <app-left-side *ngIf="item==0"></app-left-side>
      <app-right-side *ngIf="item==1"></app-right-side>
  </div>
</div>
```

a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-daw4d9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-sorting-example.html)

See that you only interchange the elements of the array [0,1]. If this array who say to Angular which component must show in first time

NOTE: This tecnica only is util if we don't store data in the components, think that each drop the components are new and initializeted

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more details.  Especially the code of  moveItemInArray code and how you reached this.innerComponenets (what hook used and what type).

Result would also suggest you are hooking to prototype instead of instance of HtmlElement.

EDIT:

You need to instantiate components in array. In your array you have prototypes of the right and left component. What you need now to do is for example to build array of INSTANCES of the components.
in example ;ike so :

```
for (const component of innerComponenets) {
     const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent<componentModel or any>(component);
innerComponentsInstancesReferences.push( componentRef);
    }
```

That componentRef array containing INSTANCES you use in ngFor. Then Templates/View would understand that you want REFERENCED INSTANCES components to be displayed. Now you did simply "tell" to tamplate "display to me prototype of my components"

please refere to the article: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

and componentRef type documentation: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef

Types are ESSENTIAL

PS> May work also if you use [ngFor]  that would not use STRING but would EVALUATE probably your component so shortly speaking instantiate it. I am not sure if that would work

Comment: I added details in code example, It is more clear?

Comment: Well. That will be probably reason. You can provide components but probably what you provide is PROTOTYPE not INSTANCE. So type of thing you are providing you would have to run with "new <Component>" or in other words INSTANTIATE COMPONENT. In more simply words you are provide CODE of the class not it's executed code (initiated). then Array will hold function/class code or any other. If you want function/class to give you instance you have to run it . function like  myFunction() ... object/class by new keyword. Nothing else come to my mind now.

Comment: How?
innerComponenets: Array<Component> = [
   RightSideComponent,
   LeftSideComponent,
  ];
It's get error: "Type 'typeof RightSideComponent' has no properties in common with type 'Component'"

Comment: Simplest would be add to an array already instituted code or more exactly reference to that instantiated object/class

Comment: Before you assigne RightSideComponent to an array  you have to instantiate it . This article may help https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader . 
See this line: viewContainerRef.createComponent<AdComponent>(adItem.component);

Comment: Ty to use [ngFor] as well please so it may evaluate string prototype. Maybe it will work.

Comment: too much complex, you can solve with a simple *ngIf :)

Answer (score 0):

Statement `{{item}}` displays values from array innerComponenets that are actually constructor functions. They are draggable thanks to the directive `cdkDrag` on containing `<div>` element.

If you have some static list of draggable components, you don't need any array and *ngFor structural directive. Just put them one after one in html code.

```
<app-left-side cdkDrag></app-left-side>
<app-right-side cdkDrag></app-right-side>
```

Comment: I thought about it, but my problem is what I give in the first parameter to the function drop:             
 drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    moveItemInArray(this.innerComponenets, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
  }